# Created a mysql database but can't seem to find it anywhere

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I just cloned a repo from github and bundle installed everything and created a mysql db via rake db:create. I migrated the database and everything....however, I have no idea where it is located? Usually when I use sqlite, it's in the db/ folder...but this database is not. where can I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in your MySQL config file. Usually it's called `my.cnf`. Where to find this config on your system, we can't say :-)

Look for `datadir` in a config file

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql/
```

Comment: datadir         = __PREFIX/var/db/mysql

Found this. All I want to do is add some base data to the db so I can run the app...but i dont know where this location is on my machine?

Comment: Ah, you don't need the data dir. You need to connect to the server. Try running `mysql -u root -p your_database`

Comment: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

That is what it says when I try to connect. I want to view the database using something like navicat...is that possible?

Comment: I don't know navicat, but surely it's possible. You just have to sort out these authentication issues. But that's off-topic (and is easily googlable).

Answer (score 0):

MySQL works a bit differently than sqlite. Whereas sqlite writes a database directly to a file (in your db/ directory in the case of rails), MySQL writes it to a server (usually located on the same machine as your application, but not always). I would be surprised if an app you cloned off of github let you create a mysql database right off the bat. You need to set up a mysql server and set a password for it. If you're running Ubuntu -- as I am -- [these](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/serverguide/C/mysql.html) are some good instructions. Then you need to configure your `config/database.yml` file accordingly.

Comment: I am doing this all on my local machine...didn't have any problems setting it up.

Comment: Well check your `config/database.yml` file to find out what port it's connecting to your server on and which username/password it's using to log in.